# Access all column names in pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

For the data frame in this image, why is the `count` column the only one I can access and print via `print(df.columns)`? In other words, why cant I access or print `Q`?

[image]

For example, when I print out the column names, I only print `count`.

```
print(df.columns) 
Index(['count'], dtype='object')
```

I can access both column names if I do this little hack, but it’s hacky (And I have to write a file):

```
df.to_csv('df.csv',header=True)
df2 = pd.read_csv("df.csv")

print(df2.columns)
Index(['Q', 'count'], dtype='object')
```

How do I access both column names without writing a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Q is the name of the index so it can only be accessed using `df.index`.

You can change Q into a column and access both columns at once:

```
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True) 
print(df.columns)
```